# How to use {{$randomInt}} in request body and save it in environment

Tags: javascript, postman, web-api-testing

I am trying to generate a random number using {{$randomInt}} and writing this script in pre-request script to get and set the value in an environment

```
let rand_int = pm.variables.replaceIn('{{$randomInt}}')
pm.environment.set("rand_int", rand_int)
```

But I want to use {{$randomInt}}  directly in the body and store the value directly in the environment from the request body.  Is there any way to do it?

Suppose this is my request body. When I send the request I want to auto-set that random value in the environment.

```
{
   "gårdsnummer": {{$randomInt}}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're using an environment variable in the body of the request you don't need or shouldn't use the `$`. The following should work:

```
{
    "gårdsnummer": {{rand_int}}
}
```

Comment: What I'm assuming here is that you're trying to use the random int you generated and then proceeded to save with environment variable `rand_int`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this is not what I want. If there is any way so that no need to write the pre-request script. In the request body, I want to use {{$randomInt}} and then hit send button that data is automatically saved to the environment.

Comment: That's not something you can do in the body of the request, you can generate a random int in the body but not save it to the environment, that's a function of the pre-request script or you could do it in the test tab after you receive the response.